# I'm making a Discord bot that is supposed to read from a text file and send called for line

Tags: discord.py

I'm new to this coding space, and what I'm trying to do is have the discord bot respond to slash command with it's specified line.

I have it where it works, but it responds to the command with the line below what is being called for.  Here's what I have so far

```
@slash.slash(name="f2pquest", description="Lists all available f2p quest")
async def f2pquest(ctx, *, word: str):
    await ctx.send('Checking File please stand by.')
    with open("f2pquest.txt", "r") as f:
        searching = re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(word), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search
        line = True
        while line:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            if searching(line):
                await ctx.send(f.readline())
                return
    await ctx.send("Quest not found")
```

Comment: Is it not just `ctx.send(line)`? `f.readline()` will read the next line below `line` that has already been read.

Comment: No worries - given it as an answer so you could mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be `await ctx.send(line)`. `f.readline()` will read the next line below the `line` that has already been read.